# class header.h not included in main

Tags: c++, class, constructor, implementation, header-files

So for some reason when i try to compile i get an error that in main.cpp: value and balance are not declared in scope.

i used #include "account.h" in main so why are they not defined?

also do you see any issues with my class, including the constructor and destructor.

account.cpp

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include "account.h"

account::account(){


}

account::~account(){

}

int account::init(){
cout << "made it" << endl;
  balance = value;

}

int account::deposit(){
  balance = balance + value;
}

int account::withdraw(){
  balance = balance - value;
}
```

main.cpp

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include "account.h"

//Function for handling I/O
int accounting(){


string command;

cout << "account> ";
cin >> command;
account* c = new account;

    //exits prompt  
    if (command == "quit"){
        return 0;
        }

    //prints balance
    else if (command == "init"){
        cin >> value;
        c->init();
        cout << value << endl;
        accounting();
        }

    //prints balance
    else if (command == "balance"){
        account* c = new account;
        cout << " " << balance << endl;
        accounting();
        }

    //deposits value
    else if (command == "deposit"){
        cin >> value;
        c->deposit();
        accounting();
        }

    //withdraws value
    else if (command == "withdraw"){
        cin >> value;
        cout << "withdrawing " << value << endl;
        accounting();
        }

    //error handling    
    else{
        cout << "Error! Command not supported" << endl;
        accounting();
        }               
}


 int main() {

     accounting();


return 0;
}
```

account.h

```
class account{

private:

int balance;

public:

    account();  // destructor
    ~account(); // destructor
    int value;
    int deposit();
    int withdraw();
    int init();

};
```

sorry if the code has bad style, i had a hard time with the stack overflow editor.

Comment: You should be using include guards and not be using `new`.

Answer (score 1):

you are referring to `value` and `balance` as if they are normal variables, but they are not - they are instance-variables. you should have an object in which to refer to them:

```
account c;
cout << "withdrawing " << c.value << endl;
```

if you are accessing them from inside a method - say, from `account::deposit` - then `value` is a syntactic sugar for `this->value`, so you can use it this way; the object is effectively `*this`. these statements are equivalent:

```
balance += value;
balance += this->value;
balance += (*this).value;
```

Answer (score 0):

`value` and `balance` are members of `class account` and they are suppose to be accessed as `c->value` and `c->balance`. But `balance` is a `private` member, you can't use it in `main()`. You need to write some accessor function like:

```
int account::GetBalance() const
{
    return balance;
}
```

and then call it as

```
cout << " " << c->GetBalance() << endl;
```

Also, you should free the allocated memory for `c` by calling .

```
delete c;
```